# im planing to buy BTC miner but the place im keeping it in suffers of power cuts everyday for approximately 15 minutes. will it operate?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, bitcoin-wallet-app, asicminer

im buying bitmain s9 for the 1st time and i have 0 experiences. if the power cut off for like 15-20 min everyday and come back will the miner operate by it self ? or i have to do it my self everyday. also will this affect the miner performance ?